# Using graph API and creating a link on the event page

Tags: php, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I must be missing something really obvious.

I have created successfully an Event with the graph API

I now want to put a link on the event page

When i use the code below, it creates a message but not a link. So please someone what am i missing. I do get a linkid back as well as you can see the message on the page.

So this is the pretty simple code.

```
        $fb = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'      => FB_APP_ID,
        'secret'     => FB_APP_SECRET,
        'cookie'     => true,
        'fileUpload' => true 
        ));            
        $fb->setAccessToken($_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_ACCESSCODE' ]);


        $data = array(   'access_token' => $_SESSION[ $eid.'_FB_USER_ACCESSCODE' ], 
                         'link'         => 'http://www.thedomain.com', 
                         'message'      => "To purchase your tickets"
                      );        
        $result = $fb->api($newFBEventId."/feed","post",$data);
```

Thanks

Comment: Some more info, When i use the GraphAPI explorer and do a get on the LINK iD returned in the result, it says i have created a type = status not link

    "message": "To purchase your tickets try 1", 
      "type": "status", 
      "application": {
       "name": "PBO event Ann(test)", 
       "canvas_name": "pbo_event_announce_t", 
        "namespace": "pbo_event_announce_t", 
        "id": "200264620060959"
      },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Bug and its reported and marked as confidential
With the below text and its also contain security hole

[bug report link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/320152154697289)

Below is my bug report text.
*Other details on this report are shown to Facebook employees only*

I recently attempted to post on an event's wall using the Graph API, but only the message is posted; Everything else is not showing. e.g.

- Link
- Picture
- etc

There is one more big thing that the post doesn't show; That this post is post "via a Facebook app"

**Note:** posting on a page or user wall worked and also normal messages posted on an event 's wall.

**The most important thing** is when the post is shown on the event's wall "it does not show that its posted by a Facebook Application".
This is very dangerous; For example I can make an application and post nonsense on a user's event wall.  People will think that this is posted by the user.

***Thanks***